# PHP SoapClient unable to work with https WS

Tags: php, wsdl, soap-client

i have a problem working with PHP SoapClient with a WS (WSDL) that contains https.
my PHP version is 5.2.5.
before you ask, yes, i am using PHP's Soap and openSSL extentions.

the URL i am trying to reach is:
https://id3check.gb.co.uk/gbportalinternational/aspx/id3check_1b.asmx?WSDL

the code i am using:

```
$url = "https://id3check.gb.co.uk/gbportalinternational/aspx/id3check_1b.asmx?WSDL";
$options["connection_timeout"] = 25;  
$options["location"] = $url;

$client = new SoapClient($url,$options);
```

it fails while constructing the SoapClient, and i get the following error:

> Warning: SoapClient::SoapClient(https://id3check.gb.co.uk/gbportalinternational/aspx/id3check_1b.asmx?WSDL): failed to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. in C:\MY-DEV-FOLDER\index.php on line 42 Warning: SoapClient::SoapClient(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "https://id3check.gb.co.uk/gbportalinternational/aspx/id3check_1b.asmx?WSDL" in C:\MY-DEV-FOLDER\index.php on line 42 Exception thrown - SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://id3check.gb.co.uk/gbportalinternational/aspx/id3check_1b.asmx?WSDL'

can anyone tell me what is the problem?

thanks

Erez

Answer (score 12):

You will need to have OpenSSL enabled in PHP to be able to retrieve content over https.

Uncomment this line in php.ini

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Look for the `openssl` section in your phpinfo():

```
OpenSSL support => enabled  
OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009
OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009
```

Answer (score 2):

I just ran the code you gave and it worked perfectly:

```
<?php
$url = "https://id3check.gb.co.uk/gbportalinternational/aspx/id3check_1b.asmx?WSDL";
$options["connection_timeout"] = 25;
$options["location"] = $url;
$options['trace'] = 1;

$client = new SoapClient($url,$options);

print_r($client->__getFunctions());
```

results in

```
Array
(
    [0] => ID3CheckInitialise_1bResponse ID3CheckInitialise_1b(ID3CheckInitialise_1b $parameters)
    [1] => ID3AddressLookupInitialise_1bResponse ID3AddressLookupInitialise_1b(ID3AddressLookupInitialise_1b $parameters)
    [2] => ID3Check_1bResponse ID3Check_1b(ID3Check_1b $parameters)
    [3] => AddressLookup_1bResponse AddressLookup_1b(AddressLookup_1b $parameters)
)
```

So maybe you should check if there are any network problems: Is there a firewall blocking the communication from within your server process? (I assume it's IIS?) You may also want to check `safe_mode` settings, although I doubt this is the problem here.