# SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from url

Tags: php, soap, ssl

While executing the following line I get this error:

`$client = new soapclient('https://example.com/xxx/pgw?wsdl=xyz.wsdl');`

Error:

`SoapFault: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://localhost:8080/xxx/pgw?wsdl=xyz.wsdl' : failed to load external entity "http://localhost:8080/xxx/pgw?wsdl=xyz.wsdl" in SoapClient->SoapClient() (line 39 of /var/www/.../myscript.php).`

I have checked the URL in my browser and that's ok.
What can cause the error?

Comment: Do you have SSL enabled? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726242/php-soapclient-unable-to-work-with-https-ws

Comment: @cillosis Yes. OpenSSL is enabled

Comment: Can you paste your code into the question ...

Answer (score 3):

I ran across this same issue today, after several hours and after trying `file_get_contents` on my WSDL URL, I noticed that I was getting a permission denied error in my apache error log.  I figured out that SELinux was the culprit.  I believe by default, SELinux blocks httpd from making its own network requests (at least on Fedora).

The fix was: `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1`, which then allowed Apache to connect to the remote service (it worked for both SSL and non-SSL requests).