# file_get_contents permission denied for external wsdl

Tags: php, http

I have three boxes in my network

Box#1 - a RHEL box with apache and php (basically a LAMP box)  
Box#2 - a windows box with JBoss hosting a WSDL using apache axis 2   
Box#3 - another windows box (basically a XAMPP box -- more on the third box later)

When I try to run a PHP script on box#1 that uses a SoapClient object to access box#2's  WSDL in a browser it returns:

> > Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080/axis2/services/TheService?wsdl' : failed to load external entity

I then tried on box#2 just to simply file_get_contents of the wsdl file I get back:

> > Warning: file_get_contents(http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080/axis2/services/TheService?wsdl): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /application/test.php on line 4

HOWEVER! when I run the last script (file_get_contents) via telnet (command line) when logged in as the same user running apache it returns the WSDL's contents... (!)

--

I tried running the same code on a windows box (box #3) with what appears to be very similar PHP.ini settings to box#2 if not as identical as they could be and I was able to use the wsdl and get the contents of the WSDL file without a problem.

--

I searched (stackoverflow and google) and saw other people had the same issues and tried solutions where listed including:

- My PHP.ini's max_file_size is set to 128M (larger than the wsdl)
- allow_url_fopen is set to on

Just to see if it worked on box#1 I tried using cURL to get the contents of the file and it did not return anything.

If anyone can give me any insight it would be greatly appreciated. I'm sure there's a setting in PHP.ini that I am missing or something pretty minor.

Comment: What does your browser shows you if you open `http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080/axis2/services/TheService?wsdl` from a browser?

Comment: It displays the WSDL's contents

Comment: I suggest you hook in with a network sniffer and check what happens on the HTTP protocol level when you request with PHP. Is that 200 OK or something else for the request (not browser, but PHP). You can also try: `var_dump($http_response_header);` directly after the file_get_contents line. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php

Comment: Warning: file_get_contents(http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080/axis2/services/TheService?wsdl): failed to open stream: Permission denied in  /application/test.php on line 4 Notice: Undefined variable: http_response_header in /application/test.php on line 5 NULL

Comment: Do the network sniffing. It will probably turn out that there is no HTTP request performed at all. Paste your code verbatim (just mask the digits of the IP).

Comment: I'm going to plead ignorance on how to do what you suggested via a packet sniffer. Let me do some research...

Comment: Here is the code verbatim: <?php echo file_get_contents("hxxp://X.X.X.X:8080/axis2/services/AuthenticationService?wsdl");" and here is the output verbatim: "Warning: file_get_contents(hxxp://X.X.X.X:8080/axis2/services/AuthenticationService?wsdl): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/songfile/test.php on line 2"  Note I changed http to hxxp to prevent S.O. from making creating a link.

Answer (score 8):

I ran across this same issue today, after several hours and after trying `file_get_contents` on my WSDL URL, I noticed that I was getting a permission denied error in my apache error log.  I figured out that SELinux was the culprit.  I believe by default, SELinux blocks httpd from making its own network requests (at least on Fedora).

The fix was: `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1`, which then allowed Apache to connect to the remote service (it worked for both SSL and non-SSL requests).

Also answered here: [SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532790/soap-error-parsing-wsdl-couldnt-load-from-url/)