# SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://***?wsdl'

Tags: php, ssl, soap

I have Soap client that works with pem file

```
$url = "https://test_site.com/test?wsdl";
$action = 'http://xmlns.test_site.com/CoreObjects/GetData';

$client = new SoapClient(
    $url,
    [
        'stream_context'=> stream_context_create([
            'ssl' => [
                'local_cert'        => 'keys/includesprivatekey.pem',
                'passphrase'        => 'secret_word',
                'verify_peer'       => false,
                'verify_peer_name'  => false,
                'allow_self_signed' => true,
            ]
        ]),
        'cache_wsdl'    => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
        'trace'         => 1,
        'exceptions'    => 1,
        'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
        'verifypeer' => false,
        'verifyhost' => false,
    ]
);

echo $client->__doRequest($xml, $url, $action, 1);
```

When I try to send request without local_cert file, I receive responce from API with NULL cert file. When I adding local_cert file I receive fatal exception:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing
>   WSDL: Couldn't load from
>   'https://test_site.com/test?wsdl' :
>   failed to load external entity
>   "https://test_site.com/test?wsdl" in
>   /srv/index.php

This is pem file example:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIICfzCCAjGgAwIBAgIKAYoCQucBEgIF1TANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQQFADBdMQswCQYD
VQQGEwJVQTEOMAwGA1UEBxQFSVRfR08xDjAMBgNVBAoUBUlUX0dPMQ4wDAYDVQQL
FAVJVF9HTzEOMAwGA1UEDBQFSVRfR08xDjAMBgNVBAMUBUlUX0dPMB4XDTE1MDgy
ODA3NDAxMloXDTI1MD
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIICXDIBAAKBgQDhMZM9vKUJXMEHR60ZPF9vmGF5pJvx3jL5kY491sRmgnS4eluV
kvqSnXfrT+ZG82nGYZhRiLVnwKvE6/Zv8QnCSJsPCwTffEuF147CPW4/5ofMA97e
tn7xr557lckVALHwAfGiDXJLkMAsECc4AoGGOs9Iv6a5ru+AXlRDW63VGQIDAQAB
AoGAbUsBOiJXOs8AhAb+
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Whats wrong?

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Upd:

> Your question has been identified as a possible duplicate of another
>   question. If the answers there do not address your problem, please
>   edit to explain in detail the parts of your question that are unique.

No, It is not duplicate. I have certificate that I need send to client.
If I remove **local_cert** from stream_context I will not receive an error on first step when downloading wsdl file, but receive an error from client api.

The solution in [Does PHP SoapClient support HTTPS connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28109505/does-php-soapclient-support-https-connections) was next

> I have the same trouble on Windows with php 5.6 and it works fine on Linux with php 5.6.
>
> > Working in LInux environment indeed solved the issue

This is not solution. I work in Ubuntu 16.04 with php7.0 and trying on php5.6

Comment: As error showing, WSDL file does not exist on provided the path, make sure that file exists on the path.

Comment: If I try to run https://test_site.com/test?wsdl in browser I receive wsdl file

Comment: see this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28109505/does-php-soapclient-support-https-connections   may it help you

Comment: You can use the function to see what are the certificate locations. I don't need it, I set pem file in stream_context.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does PHP SoapClient support HTTPS connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28109505/does-php-soapclient-support-https-connections)

Comment: >> I have the same trouble on Windows with php 5.6 and it works fine on Linux with php 5.6. Why duplicate? I have PHP7.0 on Ubuntu

Comment: Is this already fixed? I have the same problem and can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's late but if anyone read this cause is having the same problem, this is probably related to an issue with the certificate.

The .pem certificate must have the "PRIVATE KEY" not the "RSA PRIVATE KEY" you can reissue it from a .pfx or a .p12 using openssl, with the next commands:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in *certname.*extension -out cert.pem -clcerts -nokeys
openssl pkcs12 -in *certname.*extension -out key.pem -nocerts -nodes
```

Take in account that you need to merge manually the result in the "cert.pem" deleting all the text that isn't between the tags:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEvQIBADANB.....GqvF7B/rM=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

and copying the private key at the end of the result file

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvQIBADANB.....kDIjNMnIzOQ=
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: This does not work on my side.

Comment: @TomS As i said in the response, probably it's caused by the certificate. If it's not your case then I'll recommend you to indicate in the "host" file the ip related to the domain you need to connect for get the WSDL.