# SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'HTTPS Not working with https

Tags: php, xml, soap

I have to use `SOAP` to transfer date into our `ERP` system. The problem is when I'm using `http` `wsdl` everything works fine but if I change link to `https` then I have an error:
`SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'HTTPS...`
I don't really understand this because on a web server I can bind both addresses `http` or `https`. And I can open open in the web browser both without any issues. 
Do I need to add something extra in my code to allow `https`?

My current request (standard):

```
     $UserID = 'domain\username';
        $Pwd = "password";
        $ns = 'HTTP://URL/file.svc?wsdl';

        if (!defined('USERPWD')){define('USERPWD', $UserID.':'.$Pwd);};

// we unregister the current HTTP wrapper
        stream_wrapper_unregister('http');
// we register the new HTTP wrapper
        stream_wrapper_register('http', 'NTLMStream') or die("Failed to register protocol");


        $options['trace'] = 1;
        $options['soap_version'] = SOAP_1_1;
        $options['compression']  = SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT;

        try
        {

// Initialize Soap Client
           $client = new NTLMSoapClient($ns,$options);
            $client->setUSERPWD(USERPWD);
```

This is example when working but once I change url to `https` then everything stop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does PHP SoapClient support HTTPS connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28109505/does-php-soapclient-support-https-connections)

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I tried already those examples. Nothing still the same. Different PHP versions. I don't have self signed certificate. I have standard one